# How can I reference a structure of data as an argument for sprintf in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a sprintf-ready string: `The string name is %s and it has %s of %s`, the idea is that this sprintf-ready string might change and **so might the second argument to sprintf** and there-in lies the issue:

There's no way, in PHP, to dynamically reference a structure. What should I do here? I really want to be able to change that second argument.

Code:

```
$data = $data_received_from_object;

sprintf(
    'The string name is %s and it has %s of %s',
    $data['key1'],
    $data['key2'],
    ..
);
```

But this is hardcoding it. I'm looking for a way for sprintf to be able to tell "aha, this is an array with keys, I'll just keep appending arguments to myself from this variable, with the same keys".

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vsprintf(
    'The string name is %s and it has %s of %s',
    $data
);
```

Manual [here](https://php.net/vsprintf).

But with support of `...` operator you still can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(
    'The string name is %s and it has %s of %s',
    ...$data
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You're an angel. Just got to the documentation reading the *printf functions but I didn't know that it does this, but the question is, will it deal properly with arrays with keys? I'm about to test but just thought you might want to edit the answer to reflect my use-case. // Edit: Works. Damn, this is some PHP ninja-ery.